# Forward from AWS ELB to insecure port on the EC2 instance

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I fear that this might be a programming question, but I am also hopeful that it is common enough that you might have some suggestions.

I am moving to a fail-over environment using AWS elastic load balancers to direct the traffic to the EC2 instances. Currently, I have set up the ELB with a single EC2 instance behind it.  You will see why in a moment. This is still in test mode, although it is delivering content to my customers using this ELB -> EC2 path.

In each of my production environments (I have two) I have an AWS certificate on the load balancer and a privately acquired security certificate on the EC2 instance. The load balancer listeners are  configured to send traffic received on port 443 to the secure port (443) on the EC2 instance. This is working; however, as I scale up to more EC2 instances behind the load balancer, I have to buy a security certificate for each of these EC2 instances.

Using a recommendation that was proposed to me, I have set up a test environment with a new load balancer and its configured EC2 server. This ELB server sends messages received on its port 443 to port 80 on the EC2 system. I am told that this is the way it should be done - limit encryption/decryption to the load balancer and use unencrypted communication between the load balancer and its instances.

Finally, here is  my problem. The HTML pages being served by this application use relative references to the embedded scripts and other artifacts within each page. When the request reaches the EC2 instance (the application server) it has been demoted to HTTP, regardless of what it was originally.This means that the references to these embedded artifacts are rendered as insecure (HTTP). Because the original page reference was secure (HTTPS), the browser refuses to load these insecure resources.

I am already using the header X-Forwarded-Proto within the application to determine if the original request at the load balancer was HTTP or HTTPS. I am hoping against hope that there is some parameter in the EC2 instance that tells it to render relative reference in accordance to the received X-Forwarded-Proto header. Barring that, do you have any ideas about how others have solved this problem?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Why would you have to buy a security certificate for each of these EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is the right way to go by having the SSL termination at ELB/ALB and then having a security group assigned to EC2 that only accepts traffic from ELB/ALB.

However responding with https urls based on the X-Forwarded-Proto request headers or based on custom configuration, needs to be handle in your application code or webserver.